# Can my iPhone app register to receive push notifications meant for another app?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

This may be a pretty basic question, but here goes. I develop an iPhone app that is a third-party client for a popular webapp. This webapp has it's own iPhone app to which it publishes push notifications. Is it possible for my app to register to receive push notificatons Sent by the webapp and intended for the webapp's native iPhone app?  Or is this prevented by certificate magic as I suspect?

Comment: I would check out the push notification sample code. Look for a certificate being passed as part of the registration. I think if your application registered with their server, it would receive the pushes as well. My suspicion is not that it requires a certificate, but that you actually register with the application vendor's push server. They may not like your application, or your application may not be allowed to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple allow you to have apps with either a generic app ID in the format:

```
12345678.*
```

Or an explicit app ID in the format:

```
12345678.com.myCompanyName.myAppName
```

However, they only allow applications with explicit app IDs to register for APN (Apple Push Notification) Service.  Therefore it is not possible for more than one specific iPhone app to receive the same notification.

As Farcaller says, this is not a technical limitation but an imposed one.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

From the technical point of view, you can register at another server with device token. You just need to know, where to register and what protocol does it use. Still you wouldn't be able to receive notifications, as they are routed depending on the application id, and you can't mimic that.